# Use Generic Type and Interface in building a List with C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have the following Interface:

```
public interface IModel
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a dozen classes that implement, examples:

```
public interface Obj1 : IObj1
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public interface Obj2 : IObj2
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Both IObj1 and IObj2 implement IModel:

```
public interface IObj1 : IModel {}
public interface IObj2 : IModel {}
```

In my Unit Tests I create mock Lists with values for each object. Currently I have code that looks like this:

```
public static List<IObj1> Obj1ListCacheMock()
{
    var list = new List<IObj1>();

    list.Add(new Obj1() { Code = "S1", Description = "Test 1" });
    list.Add(new Obj1() { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 2" });
    list.Add(new Obj1() { Code = "S3", Description = "Test 3" });

    return list;
}

public static List<IObj2> Obj2ListCacheMock()
{
    var list = new List<IObj1>();

    list.Add(new Obj2() { Code = "S1", Description = "Test 1" });
    list.Add(new Obj2() { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 2" });
    list.Add(new Obj2() { Code = "S3", Description = "Test 3" });

    return list;
}
```

My goal is to have have just one method that returns a list of test objects. Something like:

```
public static List<IModel> Obj2ListCacheMock<IModel>()
{
    var list = new List<IModel>();

    list.Add(new { Code = "S1", Description = "Test 1" });
    list.Add(new { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 2" });
    list.Add(new { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 3" });

    return list;
}
```

This code errors with:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from '' to 'IModel'

How do I make this work or is there a better approach to meet my goal?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: @GendoIkari, I updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a generic method with a constraint for a [parameterless constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

```
public static List<T> GetListCacheMock<T>() where T : IModel, new()
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    list.Add(new T { Code = "S1", Description = "Test 1" });
    list.Add(new T { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 2" });
    list.Add(new T { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 3" });

    return list;
}
```

Then, use it like so:

```
List<Obj1> obj1s = GetListCacheMock<Obj1>(); //Assuming Obj1 is class  with a parameterless constructor
List<Obj2> obj2s = GetListCacheMock<Obj2>(); //Same for Obj2
```

If your classes doesn't have parameterless constructor you can pass a `Func<T>` to create the type instances:

```
public static List<T> GetListCacheMock<T>(Func<T> getNew) where T : IModel
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    var item1 = getNew();
    item1.Code = "S1";
    item1.Description = "Test 1";

    list.Add(item1);
    ...

    return list;
}
```

Finally

```
List<Obj1> obj1s = GetListCacheMock<Obj1>(() => new Obj1(...));
```

Comment: Perfect. I had tried a constraint but didn't have the second param "new()" -- how does make this work?

Comment: @Josh: `new()` ensure you that `T` will have a public parameterless constructor. This allow you create instances of `T`.

Comment: The only issue I ran into is that I need the return value to be a List of the Interface, opposed to object. So instead of List<Obj1> it needs to be a List<IObj1>. If this is something you think that can be solved I can post as a new question.

Comment: I figured it out, just passed to params (class and interface): 
public static List<T1, T2> GetListCacheMock<T>() where T : IModel, T2,  new()

Answer (score 1):

You still have to specify what objet you want to create.
Here:

```
new { Code = "S1", Description = "Test 1" }
```

you are creating an anonymous type that doesn't implement your IModel interface.

If you add the object name, it should work.

```
public static List<IModel> Obj2ListCacheMock<IModel>()
{
    var list = new List<IModel>();

    list.Add(new Obj1() { Code = "S1", Description = "Test 1" });
    list.Add(new Obj2() { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 2" });
    list.Add(new Obj1() { Code = "S2", Description = "Test 3" });

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the IModel type passed so I can use of the same function for different objects.

Comment: @Josh: How do you want to pass it ?

Comment: @Josh then just create a factory method that builds the corresponding object based on the type of ‘IModel’ and whatever other arguments needed to create it.